# How can I call setlocale(3) in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a program with node-ncurses.
I want to call setlocale(3) to initialize C level locale for multi-byte support.

Is there a right way to call setlocale(3) in node.js? Or, is there a npm library for it?

Comment: Ah, I think there is no module.

Comment: *I* wrote it.. http://search.npmjs.org/#/setlocale